# Vue.js style v-html with scoped css

Tags: vue.js, vue-loader

How can I style v-html content with scoped css using vue-loader?

Simple example:
component.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="icon" v-html="icon"></icon>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {icon: '<svg>...</svg>'}
    }
  }
</script>
<style scoped>
  .icon svg {
    fill: red;
  }
</style>
```

generate html
`<div data-v-9b8ff292="" class="icon"><svg>...</svg></div>`

generate css
`.info svg[data-v-9b8ff292] { fill: red; }`

As you can see v-html content don't have data-v attribute, but generate css have data-v attribute for svg.

I know this is expected behavior for vue-loader (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/359). And in this issue descendent selectors mentioned. But as you can see I use it in my css and it's not worked.

How can I style v-html content?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[As stated in my answer here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708887/vue-single-file-component-binding-data-v-xxxxxxxx-to-generated-elements)

New version of `vue-loader` (from version 12.2.0) allows you to use "deep scoped" css. You need to use it that way:

> `<style scoped>` now support "deep" selectors that can affect child
>   components using the `>>>` combinator:
>
> `.foo >>> .bar { color: red; }` will be compiled into:
>
> `.foo[data-v-xxxxxxx] .bar { color: red; }`

More informations on [the release page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases) of `vue-loader`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It's definitely should be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Adding because it happened to me, if the above doesn't work, `.foo /deep/ .bar` might work instead.

Comment: The above comments needs to be it's own answer, I was struggling with this until I read the comment.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with vue-loader 15.9.1. Anyone having the same issue ?

Answer (score 42):

I am using `vue-loader 15.9.1`. The `>>>` solution did not work for me (no effect) whereas the `/deep/`method resulted in building errors...

Here is what worked instead:

`.foo ::v-deep .bar { color: red; }`

Comment: None of the other answers worked, but this was perfect!

Comment: Thank you so much! Only your answer helped

Comment: Thank you! Just add let more context, here is the documentation link about it: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Comment: `::v-deep` is now deprecated. You should switch to `:deep(.bar)` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Using `/deep/` selector with SCSS didn't work for me but then I tried using `::v-deep` selector

e.g

```
::v-deep a {
  color: red;
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-or-v-deep-in-vue-js) answer

Comment: There's an SFC to change this to `:deep(a)`. Getting a warning `[@vue/compiler-sfc] ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use :deep(<inner-selector>) instead.`

Comment: @Mrweiner can you share the link?

Comment: Looks like this is the one https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0023-scoped-styles-changes.md

Answer (score 7):

**AS  Sarumanatee said  if the accepted answer doesn't work try:**

```
.foo /deep/ .bar { color: red; }
```

Comment: This one worked for me, "::v-deep" also. I don't know which is best ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `:deep {}`

In your case you should do:

```
<template>
   <div class="icon" v-html="icon"></div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.icon {
   :deep {
      svg {
         fill: red;
      }
   }
}
</style>
```