# Do styles in a v-html directive

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Whatever I try, it wont work, here it is:

```
<div class="text text-center">
   <p class="cosmic-links" v-html="infoText"></p>
</div>
```

Here is how it looks like in cosmicjs

```
<p>Some info</p>
<p>Some links to visit <a href="www.google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">FAQ</a></p>
```

What I am trying:

```
.cosmic-links >>> a{
   color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to vue-loader doc([source](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)):

> Some pre-processors, such as Sass, may not be able to parse >>> properly. In those cases you can use the /deep/ or ::v-deep combinator instead - both are aliases for >>> and work exactly the same.

With pre-processor Sass /deep/ or ::v-deep should work:

```
.cosmic-links /deep/ a {
  color: red;
}
```

Quick [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-sun-2g2q4?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Do you have something different than in the minimalist sandbox i provided ?

Comment: Could this be due to that the hyperlink is being overriden somewhere else globally?

Comment: I just solved the problem by removing scoped from the style tag. that's very weird

Comment: My bad, with scoped style you're right and using deep selector >>> should work. I updated it on my codesandbox and it seems to work. Howerver you seem to have the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844788/vue-js-style-v-html-with-scoped-css and replace >>> by /deep/ seems to work.
You can see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly and i have never seen /deep/ before with all the years i've been working on frontend

Comment: Maybe you're using a pre processor like sass or less.
According to the doc of vue-loader: "Some pre-processors, such as Sass, may not be able to parse >>> properly. In those cases you can use the /deep/ or ::v-deep combinator instead - both are aliases for >>> and work exactly the same." (source: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Comment: I just recently recieved this error: /deep/ combinator is no longer supported in CSS dynamic profile

Comment: Did you tried ::v-deep ? Give a look at this thread https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/913

Comment: I solved the problem and yes i also did try it without success. I think vue needs to update their documentation