# CSS @import with v-html

Tags: css, vue.js, css-import

How can I style v-html content with scoped css using `@import`?

There is an explanation on [how to use ::v-deep here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844788/vue-js-style-v-html-with-scoped-css), but in my case I'd like to include a CSS file using `@import`.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="richtext" />
</template>
...
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import 'assets/scss/imports/headers.scss';
</style>
```

I could import the style globally which does work but my goal is to only import it in this richtext component.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do it using the `src` attribute

```
<style lang="scss" src="@/assets/scss/imports/headers.scss"></style>
```

Comment: This does ignore the scoped attribute. It does work, but it's similar to loading the import globally.